# Generic XML parser design analysis

Tags: java, xml, database, parsing, xpath

We need to create a generic XML parser and rule engine which reads XMLs files and store the data in appropriate tables.

Use Case:

Suppose we have Afile1.xml coming from A

```
<x>
  <y>1</y>
  <z>a</z>
<x>
```

And a mapping in database such as

```
Source  FileName  Field             Path   
A        Afile1   table1.value1     /x/y
B        Bfile7   table1.value1     /p/q/r
A        Afile1   table1.value2     /x/z
```

We need to design a system

- to read the xml file Afile1,Bfile2
- pick the value from the file and update the value in the table.

What is the best platform to design such system, perl or Java. observing we need to parse lots of xml using xpath.
Are there any framework in Java which can help to easily build the required system.

Thank you

Comment: "Best" in terms of what? Either could do it, although it's not really clear what you actually need to do.

Comment: Pick the language, framework and tools that you are most comfortable with and then build it. Once you have it running, then you can optimize it and try to figure out if other tools could work better. Pre-mature optimization is very counter productive.

Comment: Just wanted to understand where should I look first. I have zero experience in xml parsing, and I'm comfortable with both java and perl language.

Comment: @akashr General point. If you are intending to write *any* code, always ask if someone might have done something similar before. And then see if some helpful person/group has written a generic (library) solution. Most modern software now consists of using libraries.

Comment: So I mentioned above "Are there any framework in Java which can help to easily build the required system"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO the best way is to stop and think: Is there a chance that people still have not built general XML parser?

Thank a second, two, three... Oh, my god! Surely they have done it!

Ok, now let's look for the way to parse XML. Start from some googling. Find SAX and DOM. Read about them, but wait! Do not start to implement your real application. Take a look on JAXB. Learn it a little bit. Now the tip: take a look on `@XmlAnyElement`. This is what you probably need to perform generic XML parsing.

OK, now you can convert XML documents to appropriate java object. The next phase it to store the objects in DB. Here is the question: which DB to use? Do I really need relational DB? Tip: you probably do not need. Probably you can use one of NoSql implementations that are  able to store your objects as-is. For example MongoDB.

If however you decide to use relational DB, first read about JDBC but do not use it directly. When you understand how does it it work read about JPA and think how can you use it for your task.

Enjoy :)

Comment: JAXB seems helpful. But will it help me create generic xml parser? I don't think so. I will need to create new definitions for each new xml document if I use JAXB, as well as new class,dao corresponding to each new file. That is exactly what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

If you create an XML parser (and I agree with @AlexR, don't) then you must create a fully conformant one. An "XML parser" which only implements half the spec is not an XML parser. It is a menace.

Ask yourself whether you want to implement the following:

- character encoding for a wide range of encodings
- parameter entities
- external DTDs
- internal DTDs
- general entities
- CDATA sections
- validation
- standalone
- processing Instructions

and a lot more.

If you do not understand any of these then your parser will be broken.

OK, if you STILL want to do it, read the spec. Read the spec again. Find the 1000+ conformance tests that OASIS provided. Make sure that your parser conforms to all those.

Then test it. alpha, beta.

Did you forget namespaces??

Only then release it for use.